# I have trouble understanding this line of code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

As title says..

```
playerVelocity.x = playerVelocity.x  *deceleration +acceleration.x *sensitivity;
```

I don't understand what's happening here. Or how it's possible. How can I take velocity and multiply it by deceleration of velocity and then add it again. It just makes no sense to me.

The way I'm reading it is.. I have playerVelocity and multiply it by the thing that actually slows it down, then I'm adding it again.

Sigh, sorry I'm very frustrated at this simple piece of code that seems to be very easy for everyone except me..

Would anyone mind clarifying this for me?

Comment: It's perfectly legitimate C-whatever syntax.  Whether it makes any sense in the context of the program would depend on the context of the program.  (It appears to be attempting to adjust velocity based on a steady deceleration plus some acceleration possibly supplied by a user control).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that `velocity = velocity*deceleration;`, applied at regular intervals, simply supplies a constant deceleration.  Then adding to that `acceleration*sensitivity` at the same regular intervals simply applies some variable acceleration to the otherwise-decelerating object.

The net will be an object that slowly decelerates unless "urged" onward by user input.

Comment: Thanks for breaking that down.

Answer (score 3):

`deceleration` is some coefficient describing how the velocity slows down in the absence of an acceleration.  `sensitivity` is a coefficient describing how `acceleration` affects `velocity`.   So what this line is doing is updating the velocity based on these coefficients.   Probably it is taking place in a timed loop of some kind, so that the velocity changes appropriately at those steps in your program.  Without the last half, it would just be:

```
velocity = velocity * deceleration;
```

If `deceleration` is less than 1, this relationship means the velocity will eventually head towards 0.  Adding what is, I assume, the user's input acceleration, you get your code:

```
velocity = velocity * deceleration + acceleration * sensitivity;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That helped and makes sense now. I used  Hot Lick's answer to understand it and now looking at yours it makes complete sense.